# SwiftUI Open view in two different ways using view model pattern

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, swift5

I need to open a view called RequestDetails.

There are two cases in which this view can be opened.

1. Providing the data to open this request
2. Providing a reference to a Firestore document

In this case I do not have all the details of this specific Request but I have just a reference to the Firestore document. I am using this reference to make a query as soon as this view appears and get the details about this Request `RequestDetail(reference: reference)`

```
class RequestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var request: RequestModel?
    @Published var requestReference: DocumentReference?

    init(request: RequestModel? = nil, requestReference: DocumentReference? = nil) {
        self.request = request
        self.requestReference = requestReference
    }

    func loadRequest() {
        FirestoreService().fetchDocument(documentReference: self.requestReference) { (request: RequestModel) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.request = request
            }
        }
    }

}

struct RequestDetails: View {
    @State var reference: DocumentReference?
    @State var request: RequestModel?

    @ObservedObject var vm: RequestViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if request != nil {
                Text(self.request?.senderFirstName)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            if self.vm.package == nil {
                self.vm.loadRequest()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Home: View {
    var request: RequestModel
    var reference: DocumentReference

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RequestDetail(request: request)
            RequestDetail(reference: reference)
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I'm getting a lot of errors and I'm wondering if the logic behind is ok or not. Am I using the view model pattern in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be appropriate to follow MVVM concept

```swift
struct RequestDetails: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: RequestViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.vm.request != nil {
                Text(self.vm.request!.senderFirstName)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            if self.vm.request == nil {
                self.vm.loadRequest()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Home: View {
    var request: RequestModel
    var reference: DocumentReference

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RequestDetail(vm: RequestViewModel(request: request))
            RequestDetail(vm: RequestViewModel(reference: reference))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do I pass the request or reference to the view model?

Comment: @RexhinHoxha, it is shown in `Home` view, eg. `RequestViewModel(request: request)`.